# How can I trigger cmd+h using Mac OS and firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, firefox, eventtrigger

I am using Firefox (3-6) and need to trigger cmd+h (minimize application) using Mac OS.
But I am not able to get it to work.

Problem here is that I am using a rte (this rte uses an iframe) and that one is catching shortcuts. I can get the original event and I tried to call a js-function on the parent window. But I am not able to get it working.

**Anyone got any advice for me?**

Comment: What does this code produce, when you test it at a blank/this page `javascript:void window.addEventListener("keyup", function(ev){document.title=ev.metaKey+" "+ev.keyCode}, true)` when you press CMD+H? It should change the document's title to "true 72".

Comment: this code changes the document title to "false 74" when i press the "j"-key. It does not change the document title when pressing CMD+H. Firefox gets minimized as expected (because there is no other component on the page which catches the event).

Comment: but i am not trying to catch that event i am trying to trigger it using javscript and firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD+H is an OS shortcut for mac and can therefor never be triggered using simple javascript. The only way would be to write an own firefox addOn with this functionality.